# Android ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor() throw java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Failed to redact

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I am writing an Android app which handle images on device.

I open the file descriptor of images using ContentResolver's openFileDescriptor(). But it throws an exception which I can't find from [Android API doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) for some images. It works fine for most images. About the problematic images, I can see the images without problem in the default gallery app.

Is there someone who knows why it happens?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Failed to redact
 /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/60s-70s/a2acf4b43dd94f609d605dacc6f0a2e0.jpg
at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2393)
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2369)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2352)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:190)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionWithFileNotFoundExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:153)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProviderNative.java:781)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openTypedAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1986)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1801)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1634)
at android.content.ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:1581)
--- snip ---
```

My code:

```
     if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        val pfd = mContentResolver.openFileDescriptor(
                            Uri.parse(strContentUri),
                            "r"
                        )
     // strContentUri is like "content://media/external/images/media/21052"
```

Comment: You should first tell how you obtained `strContentUri`. If you used an intent action and onActivityResult then post both. If you saved the uri string and used it later then tell so. Also tell Android version of used device.

Comment: `I can see the images without problem in the default gallery app.` You probable first see a small thumbnail. But can you open them in full size? Maybe the file is meanwhile deleted but the media store is unaware of it.

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/60s-70s/a2acf4b43dd94f609d605dacc6f0a2e0.jpg` Did you use a classic file explorer to have a look at that path?

Comment: 1. I obtained `strContentUri` from query().
2. The file is definitely not deleted, I can see the image in fullsize.
3. I can see the picture from default gallery app and file explorer in Galaxy S10.

I did some experiments about it after I post this question. It seems that the problem is definitely because of the file itself. After I delete the file, I copied it from my PC to the device again. But the problem happens. You can download the file here: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/onevideo-5a6b5.appspot.com/o/static%2Fa2acf4b43dd94f609d605dacc6f0a2e0.jpg?alt=media

Comment: From query()? But what what what? If you want help you should better show what you do.

Comment: I tried this picture file and got the same error. But I can alway open other files normally.

Comment: And it's so werid. Have you solved this problem? If you have, let me know plz, thank you for sharing.

Comment: Hi, meng. I couldn't solve this problem, yet. But this problem happens only for this image. That's what I was embarrassed, too. We need some handling code or probably there is a bug for some kind of images in Android system. Anyway, let me share the solution, when I solve it.

Comment: I probably know the reason.
In the exif information of this picture (and other pictures that have the same problem), the XMP information is not a complete xml structure, which causes an exception during MediaProvider parsing. The exception stack is:
`DatabaseUtils: Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT ?xpacket begin=...@1:52 in java.io.InputStreamReader@7447c54)
DatabaseUtils: at com.android.org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:432)
DatabaseUtils: at com.android.providers.media.util.XmpInterface.<init>(XmpInterface.java:87)`

Comment: And we temporarily circumvented it：If the XMP information is not a complete xml result, then this part of the content will not be parsed. Perhaps Android will fix this problem in the future. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @meng Thanks for sharing this result! It is really helpful sharing for me.

Comment: hi there, is there any guide on how to ignore the xml part? thank you!